# jquery $.getScript().. How to get data from external js file into array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I try to put data into js file, through "jquery $.post" and "fwrite php", and get back that data into array. How to do that?

here's the html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#button").click(function() {

            if ($("#nameput").val() != "") {
                $.post("processing.php", {
                    putname: $("#nameput").val()
                });

                var arr = [$.getScript("talk.js")];

                alert(arr[0]);
            }
        })
    })
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="text" id="nameput" />

    <button id="button">send AJAX req</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the php, I name it "processing.php" :

```
<?php
    $file = fopen("talk.js","a");
    $text = $_POST["putname"];
    fwrite($file,'"'.$text.'",');
    fclose($file);
?>
```

And "talk.js" will look like this :

```
"a","b","c",
```

Why I can't put that data from "talk.js" into array at " var arr = [$.getScript("talk.js")]; " as in html file above?

Here's what I try after I read comments. I change the scirpt into this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#button").click(function() {

        if ($("#nameput").val() != "") {
            $.post("processing.php", {
                putname: $("#nameput").val()
            }, function() {
                $.getScript("talk.js", function(data) {
                    var arr = data.split(",");
                    alert(arr[0]);

                })


            })


        }

    })
})
</script>
```

And php into this:

```
<?php
    $file = fopen("talk.js","a");
    $text = $_POST["putname"];
    fwrite($file,$text);
    fclose($file);
?>
```

But it still not work?

Comment: I found it..I change **js** file into **txt**, and use `$(selector).load()` method to make it **spilt**table text. I think $.getScript is just for loading script. thankyou all!

Answer (score 0):

here's a simplified version of your button click to help you out:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $.getScript("talk.js", function(data){
        var arr = data.split(',');
        alert(arr[0]);
    });
});
```

If you log the output of `$.getScript` you will easily see why what you're trying doesn't work.

Using this method you will get the data returned from the script (`"a","b","c"`), but you'll need to `split` it on a comma into an array. Then you can reference whichever part of the array you want.

Note that the each element of the array will have quotations around them.

Comment: So I've changed my script into this  `<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  
  $("#button").click(function(){
  
   if($("#nameput").val()!=""){
    $.post("processing.php",{putname:$("#nameput").val()});
    
    $.getScript("talk.js", function(data){
     var arr = data.split(',');
     alert(arr[0]);
    })
   }
   
  })
  
  
 })</script>`  **and php into this** `<?php
 $file = fopen("talk.js","a");
 $text = $_POST["putname"];
 fwrite($file,$text);
 fclose($file);
?>` But alert won't show up?

Comment: You should initiate the `$.getScript` request in the success callback in `$.post` to make sure the PHP script is successfully executed before you try to download `talk.js`.

Comment: do you mean like this? `<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  
  $("#button").click(function(){
  
   if($("#nameput").val()!=""){
    $.post("processing.php",{putname:$("#nameput").val()})
     .done(function(){$.getScript("talk.js",function(data){
       var arr = data.split(',');
       alert(arr[0]);
       })
      });
 
   }
   
  })
 })
 
</script>` but it still not work,,